# Port is open but external IPs have no access

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, port, mongodb

My MongoDB is running under a docker container. On the server, I can confirm that port `27017` is open. MongoDB IP Bind is set to `0.0.0.0` to `/etc/mongod.conf`

```
nmap -p 27017  127.0.0.1
PORT      STATE SERVICE
27017/tcp open  mongod
```

IpTables also have the rule

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
ACCEPT     tcp  --  localhost.localdomain  localhost.localdomain  tcp dpt:27017
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:27017
```

Also `netstat` reports Listening

```
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1004 but you should be root.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::6379                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::3001                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::3002                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::9090                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           -
```

From my computer nmap reports that the port is filtered

```
nmap -p 27017  xxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx
PORT      STATE    SERVICE
27017/tcp filtered mongod
```

How can I have access remotely to port 27017? What else to check?

EDIT : List of `iptables -L -v`

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 52 packets, 2544 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 2469  164K f2b-sshd   tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh
 2758  180K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     localhost.localdomain  localhost.localdomain  tcp dpt:27017
 4189  500K ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
 4189  500K ufw-before-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
 1136  119K ufw-after-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
 1130  119K ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
 1130  119K ufw-reject-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
 1130  119K ufw-track-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:27017

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DOCKER-USER  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    docker0  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  any    docker0  anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 ufw-before-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 ufw-after-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 ufw-reject-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 ufw-track-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 7585 1341K ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
 7585 1341K ufw-before-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
 1112  164K ufw-after-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
 1112  164K ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
 1112  164K ufw-reject-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
 1112  164K ufw-track-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  docker0 !docker0  anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DROP       all  --  any    docker0  anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain f2b-sshd (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 2469  164K RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    6   468 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-ns
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-dgm
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:netbios-ssn
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:microsoft-ds
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   90  4292 LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
    0     0 ufw-user-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 1206  254K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere
 1807  124K ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
    0     0 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
   27  1684 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:bootps dpt:bootpc
  342 17584 ufw-not-local  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             224.0.0.251          udp dpt:mdns
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
  342 17584 ufw-user-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 3556  407K ACCEPT     all  --  any    lo      anywhere             anywhere
 2917  769K ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
   39  2762 ufw-user-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
    0     0 LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  312 16348 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
   24   768 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
    6   468 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
    0     0 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10
    0     0 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    6   468 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    1    60 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW
   38  2702 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    3   180 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:80
   10   516 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:27017
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:27017
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:27017

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

firewall status

```
ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
27017                      ALLOW       Anywhere
27017/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
27017 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
27017/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: Is there a firewall in that network? You could also use `tcpdump` to see if any traffic to port 27017 arrives at this computer.

Comment: Can you add the output of `iptables -L -v` to this question? There's additional information in verbose mode that might help with the diagnostics.

Comment: @John hi, check my edit

Comment: @berndbausch check my edit

Comment: Is there any chance an external router to be set to filter that port? How can this be checked in a VM remote server?

Comment: Just a question: What about the firewall on the client?

Comment: @GarfieldBonn Thought about that, there is no problem on the client side, I used also nmap web online services. I got the same results.

Comment: I meant a firewall outside of the MongoDB server.

Comment: @berndbausch I am not sure if I understand your question. Server side firewall on/off I get the same result. Client side firewall on/off the same. I don't know if a hardware router has disabled some ports or a proxy firewall exist since the server is a VM inside an infrastructure. All I know is that before a month it worked just fine. Suddenly before a week I had to readjust the iptables and other sever settings.

Comment: By "firewall" I meant products sold by companies like F5 or Cisco that protect a network against illicit access. Or open-source ones like Shorewall (does it still exist?). A device that is separate from the client and the server. Now, if the server in question is a VM inside an infrastructure, and nothing on the client or the server blocks traffic to the MongoDB port, perhaps the infrastructure filters this port now, and something in the infrastructure changed a week or month ago.

Comment: @berndbausch yes thank you I believe that something is going wrong here. Since I am not a server expert I asked to help me in case I missed something.